# Apache POI XSLFAutoShape - Shape OffSet property

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am drawing a pptx from scratch using ApachePOI-XSLF (ooxml implementation) and I am struggling to find good documentation and good examples. Also the library isn't easy to follow and not straight forward.
I would like to know how do I set the offset of two shapes of XSFLAutoShape connected by XSLFConnectorShape.

This is my code right now:

```
        XMLSlideShow pptx = new XMLSlideShow();
        XSLFSlide slide = pptx.createSlide();

        XSLFAutoShape rectangle = slide.createAutoShape();
        rectangle.setShapeType(ShapeType.RECT);
        rectangle.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(100, 100, 100, 50));
        rectangle.setLineColor(Color.blue);
        rectangle.setFillColor(Color.lightGray);

        XSLFAutoShape miniCircle = slide.createAutoShape();
        miniCircle.setShapeType(ShapeType.ELLIPSE);
        miniCircle.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(rectangle.getAnchor().getMaxX() + 200, rectangle.getAnchor().getCenterY()+50, 1, 1));
        miniCircle.setLineColor(Color.yellow);
        miniCircle.setFillColor(Color.yellow);

        connect(slide, rectangle, miniCircle);

        XSLFAutoShape anotherRectangle = slide.createAutoShape();
        anotherRectangle.setShapeType(ShapeType.RECT);
        anotherRectangle.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(miniCircle.getAnchor().getMaxX() + 200, 100, 100, 50));
        anotherRectangle.setLineColor(Color.blue);
        anotherRectangle.setFillColor(Color.lightGray);

        connect(slide, miniCircle, anotherRectangle);
```

and the connect method:

```
public static void connect(XSLFSlide slide, XSLFAutoShape start, XSLFAutoShape end){
    XSLFConnectorShape connector = slide.createConnector();
    connector.setAnchor(new Rectangle2D.Double(start.getAnchor().getX() + 100, start.getAnchor().getCenterY(), 100, 1));

    CTConnector ctConnector = (CTConnector)connector.getXmlObject();
    ctConnector.getSpPr().getPrstGeom().setPrst(STShapeType.STRAIGHT_CONNECTOR_1);

    CTNonVisualConnectorProperties cx = ctConnector.getNvCxnSpPr().getCNvCxnSpPr();

    // connection start
    CTConnection stCxn = cx.addNewStCxn();
    stCxn.setId(start.getShapeId());
    // side of the rectangle to attach the connector: left=1, bottom=2,right=3, top=4
    stCxn.setIdx(3);

    CTConnection endCxn = cx.addNewEndCxn();
    endCxn.setId(end.getShapeId());
    // side of the rectangle to attach the connector: left=1, bottom=2,right=3, top=4
    endCxn.setIdx(3);
}
```

The output of is:
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YO2Q7.png)

But I want this:
[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3pq6K.png)

p.s. I edit the post because someone thumbs down the post without a reason.  I added more info but still complicated because the library is complicated :-/. would mind help and thumbs up again ? If you cannot help at least do not destroy my reputation. I am serious developer. Tkx.

Comment: why my post has been voted down ?

Comment: Sorry I can't help much, but I suspect your question was voted down because it had very little to go on. You have fixed that. Much better question now. Unfortunately, the PPTX API in POI is basically limited in capability. I don't even know if it has a dedicated developer right now. The great thing about Open Source projects is that you have the source available, and you can add in what you need. Unfortunately, until there is someone to take ownership of that part of the project, it will remain complicated and inconsistent. Maybe it could be you?

Comment: Oh, sorry to hear the project hasn't a dedicated developer. Right now I was asking for a feature that Power Point no longer supports it. When I tested I did everything on KeyNote and it supports the offset, however if I export to pptx and open it up, the offset is just ignored. Now that I have an Office license I can work closely to PowerPoint.  Thanks for your input. And thanks for voting it up again.

Comment: We end up buying the license and we succeed. So for creating ppt's rather than reading it, I recommend the aspose.slides. Thank you